# Get rid of warning "JVM flavor 'sun' not understood"

Tags: java

I just installed **fop**, which is a Java binary, with **apt**. When I launch fop, I get next warning:

```
[warning] /usr/bin/fop: JVM flavor 'sun' not understood
```

I wonder if it possible to fix the cause of the warning and get rid of it.

Here is the output of `apt-cache policy fop`:

```
fop:
  Installed: 1:2.1-7
  Candidate: 1:2.1-7
  Version table:
 *** 1:2.1-7 500
        500 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

That of `java -version`:

```
openjdk version "11.0.5" 2019-10-15
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.5+10-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.118.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.5+10-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.118.04, mixed mode, sharing)
```

And finally `update-java-alternatives -l`:

```
java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64      1111       /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64
java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64       1081       /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64
java-1.9.0-openjdk-amd64       1091       /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.9.0-openjdk-amd64
```

Comment: How did you installed `fop`? Please add output of `apt-cache policy fop`, `java -version`, `update-java-alternatives -l` to the question.

Comment: I issued `sudo apt install fop`. I will add the output of the commands editing my question.

Answer (score 1):

The warning is emitted by the `/usr/lib/java-wrappers/java-wrappers.sh` script, because sun is not mentioned in `/usr/lib/java-wrappers/jvm-list.sh`.

What you can do to avoid the warning is set up the java environment variables yourself.
You can find out which values the java wrappers would supply by starting a fresh shell; running the java wrapper commands manually and look at the results, like this:

```
. /usr/lib/java-wrappers/java-wrappers.sh
find_java_runtime openjdk sun
echo $JAVA_HOME
echo $JAVA_CMD
```

Then, before running your `fop` command, export these variables in your environment. Example for my system:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
export JAVA_CMD=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
```

Note that doing this by hand will override any java version you may have chosen with the alternatives system.